# Maven Looking for a config file in server address, but I need it to run offline

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have some checkstyle XML configurations used in many projects that are downloaded from the server.
But I need them to be in the repository location.

It can be compared with the scenario where the local repository serves the purpose of local cache for the third-party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

From [Checkstyle-Mojo-Documentation#configLocation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/checkstyle-mojo.html):

> Potential values are a filesystem path, a URL, or a classpath resource. This parameter expects that the contents of the location conform to the xml format (Checkstyle Checker module) configuration of rulesets.
>
> This parameter is resolved (1.) as resource, (2.) URL, then (3.) file.

`sun_checks.xml` and `google_checks.xml` are [packaged with checkstyle](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/tree/master/src/main/resources) (under class path root/in default package).

So it sounds like your config file(s) is currently configured like:

```xml
 <configLocation>https://some.server.it/some-config.xml</configLocation>
 <!-- e.g.: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/raw/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml ^^ -->
```

---

If we:

> ... need them to be in the repository location

, we can stick to [How To:multi-module-confg](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html).

This involves:

1. To create a new (independant) jar artifact/pom/project:

   ```xml
   <groupId>com.foo.my</groupId>
   <artifactId>build-tools</artifactId>
   ...
   ```

   having the checkstyle config (we can also place suppressions, pmd/editor/other tool configs here;) in `src/main/resources/[com/foo/my/]my-checkstyle-config.xml`
2. `mvn install` build-tools (to use them locally), to use in "company repository": `mvn deploy` it.
3. Use it (in checkstyle-projects) like:

   ```xml
   ...
    <build>
      <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.2</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency> <!-- as plugin dependency! -->
              <groupId>com.foo.my</groupId>
              <artifactId>build-tools</artifactId>
              <version>...</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
          <configuration> <!-- pointing to the (classpath) resource (pulled by the above dependency): -->
            <configLocation>[com/foo/my/]my-checkstyle-config.xml</configLocation>
            ...
   ```

   This will fetch the config from class path respectively from local maven repository.

   `[com/foo/my]` is the *optional* package of `my-checkstyle-config.xml`, so when we put it (in build-tools) under: `src/main/resources/foo/bar/my-checkstyle-config.xml`, `configLocation` should be `/foo/bar/my-checkstyle-config.xml`.

   If it's in top/default package, then just `my-checkstyle-config.xml` or (equavalent) `/my-checkstyle-config.xml` (analogous to `whizbang/checkstyle.xml` in the How-To guide).

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but multi-module config will require change in the whole project where ever the checkstyle project has been used, I there a way it can be done at the root level.

Comment: when you place a `pluginManagement` in the "root pom" this(configuration) *will apply* to all children, *but* it can/could be overriden project (hierarchy level) wise..

Comment: when you place in `plugins` (not pluginManagement), then it *will apply* to all children "as execution" (not only "configuration")